# Сделать EditText активным после нажатия

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/famil"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
android:layout_below="@+id/name"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Фамилия"
android:inputType="textPersonName" >
```

И если зайти в приложение, то сразу появляется клавиатура. Как можно сделать чтоб это поле становилось активным только после нажатия на него?
Буду благодарен за информацию!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И если зайти в приложение, то сразу появляется клавиатура.

Вообще такое поведение ни есть `поведение по умолчанию`и из приведенной Вами разметки **не следует** что должна появляться клавиатура, по всей видимости Вы в коде ее дергаете.

Как вариант можете попробовать в манифесте у **текущей** Activity прописать следующую строчку:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Comment: Если запускаю приложение на эмуляторе, клавиатура не появляется, только мигает курсор в поле ввода. Если с телефона - появляется клавиатура

Comment: @Денис для полноты эксперимента посоветовал бы попробовать на другом телефоне, может в на данном устройстве стоят какие либо настройки специальные.